# WIndows Mobile full screen problem

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, mobile, fullscreen

I have a windows mobile professional 6.1 application and I want it to be full screen in all pages so I put the code below into my every pages constructor;

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

this works OK but "sometimes" for example when I use

```
MessageBox.Show("alert");
```

or when I try to connect internet within application and there is a problem and Windows shows me some messages popping up from the top of the screen..in this cases I lose my full screen and the top menu bar of windows becomes visible again..

any ideas?

Comment: You should mark an answer as the correct answer if that was the case. That is how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SHFullScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa930139%28v=msdn.10%29) to hide the start icon and other system areas of the screen.  There is an undocumented function named [AllKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mikefrancis/capture-all-windows-mobile-device-keys-using-the-allkeys-api) which will allow you to block some of the hardware keys (notes, recorder, green + red phone keys) from running.  It will require a lot of work because there are many ways to run programs and the taskbar has a habit of reappearing after a program is run.  Simply calling SHFullScreen once is not enough.  You'll have to handle WM_ACTIVATE messages and call SHFullScreen again and force your program to the top again.  It's a struggle against the operating system to have a true kiosk application on Windows Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Getting an app to "kiosk mode" in Windows Mobile is challenging becasue the platform simply isn't designed for it.  [This page](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/ruslantrifonov/archive/2007/05/15/Kiosk-mode-in-Windows-Mobile.aspx) has a lot of links to resources of getting it working.  Using your favorite search engine to look for "compact framework kiosk mode" is likely to bring up more as well.

Comment: tnx, I better go with the

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;